# PHP GuzzleHttp. How to make a post request with params?

Tags: php, request, httpclient, guzzle

How to make a post request with GuzzleHttp( version 5.0 ).

I am trying to do the following:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->post(
    'http://www.example.com/user/create',
    array(
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword'
    )
);
```

But I am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with the message 'No method can handle the email config key'

Answer (score 137, accepted):

> This method is now deprecated in 6.0. Instead of `body` use `form_params`

Try this

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->post(
    'http://www.example.com/user/create',
    array(
        'body' => array(
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Test user',
            'password' => 'testpassword'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This method is now deprecated in 6.0. Instead of `body` use `form_params`.

Comment: Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Answer (score 265):

Since **Marco's answer is deprecated**, you must use the following syntax (according jasonlfunk's comment) :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.example.com/user/create', [
    'form_params' => [
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ]
]);
```

## Request with POST files

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.example.com/files/post', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'file_name',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'csv_header',
            'contents' => 'First Name, Last Name, Username',
            'filename' => 'csv_header.csv'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

## REST verbs usage with params

```
// PUT
$client->put('http://www.example.com/user/4', [
    'body' => [
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ],
    'timeout' => 5
]);

// DELETE
$client->delete('http://www.example.com/user');
```

## Async POST data

Usefull for long server operations.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', 'http://www.example.com/user/create', [
    'form_params' => [
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ]
]);
$promise->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
    }
);
```

## Set headers

According to [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers), you can set headers :

```
// Set various headers on a request
$client->request('GET', '/get', [
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
    ]
]);
```

## More information for debugging

If you want more details information, you can use `debug` option like this :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.example.com/user/create', [
    'form_params' => [
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ],
    // If you want more informations during request
    'debug' => true
]);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields) is more explicits about new possibilities.

Comment: To send query string in the post requests I've found better using 'query' option inside the params, because somehow in the url string it only took the 1st one http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#query

Answer (score 56):

Note in Guzzle V6.0+, another source of getting the following error may be incorrect use of JSON as an array:

> Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST
>   request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request
>   option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the
>   "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

**Incorrect**:

```
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api', [
    'body' => [
        'name' => 'Example name',
    ]
])
```

**Correct**:

```
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api', [
    'json' => [
        'name' => 'Example name',
    ]
])
```

**Correct**:

```
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'body' => json_encode([
        'name' => 'Example name',
    ])
])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('http://demo.website.com/api', [
    'body' => json_encode($dataArray)
]);
$response = $request->getBody();
```

Add

`openssl.cafile` in `php.ini` file

Answer (score 1):

You May Easy Call Multipart Api for image uploading directly using use GuzzleHttp\Client;

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils;
use File;

$filename = $req->file('file1')->getClientOriginalName();
        $getfilePath  = $req->file('file1')->getRealPath();
        $client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8045/api/uploadImages', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => fopen($getfilePath, 'r')
        ],
        // 'headers'  => [
        //      'Content-Type' => '<Content-type header>'
        //  ]
       
    ]
]);
echo $response->getStatusCode();
$bodyresponcs = $response->getBody();
$result = json_decode($bodyresponcs);
print_r($result->status);
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Laravel`, which has `Http` wrapper over `Guzzle`, use below approach.

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://example.com/users', [
    'param1' => 'Param 1 value',
    'param2' => 'Param 2 value'
]);
```

Here is the reference [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests).